# Is there any code snippet demonstrate the harm of memory leak or fogeting free memory malloced

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I always be told that need free the memory that malloced before at last. But since many times I foget free the memory, the programe doesn't show any difference. I wonder if there any code snippet to demonstrate the harm of foget free memory malloced before. These seems be fine if I foget free them.

```
...
int i;
char *buff[64];
for( i = 0; i < 64; i++ ) {
    buff[i] = malloc(1024*100);
    strcpy( buff[i], "Some String");
    puts(buff[i]);
}
...
```

Comment: A reasonable modern computer can have multiple gigabytes of memory. You allocate less than two kilobytes. What do you think?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, how about now, I change the size

Comment: Even after the update bro, you allocate 64*1024*100 bytes which is 6.25 megabytes.

Comment: A reasonable modern computer can have multiple gigabytes of memory. You allocate less than seven megabytes. What do you think? Also, please don't silently edit your question.

Comment: Thank you guys, but I want to delete this question because I received so many "down"

Comment: Many examples can be found on BugTraq or on any Full Disclosure list.

Comment: Accept the downvotes as a learning experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I will explain the problem.

- Computers has limited memory ( modern personal one has about 8 Gigabytes).
  Operating systems and apps need the memory so their code can be loaded into it and executed by the CPU.
- Modern systems split the memory into equally sized chunks called pages, the actual page size differs from system to another
- So, the computer has limited size of pages (memory chunks).. What happens if the running processes require more pages than the limit ??

  - Simply the operating system takes a few pages from the memory and save it to the hard-disk, this known as swapping
  - Later the process may need a page that was swapped-out, so the operating system will swap it in, as hard-disks are much slower, it impacts the performance badly
  - If there is a lot of swapping operations, this is called thrashing.

So the bottom line, if there is a process who leaks memory. the system will keep thrashing and processes will wait in a long queue for the hard-disk device.

I also encourage you to learn about computer architecture and operating system to get deep insights.

Comment: thank you very much! does swapping mean copy the contents of a few pages into disk?

Comment: @Tee, yes.. this called swapping out... and the reverse operation is called swapping-in

Answer (score 1):

It is problem if you allocate lots of memory or if you allocate memory repeatedly. Allocating 64 times 100 KiB won't hurt you on modern computers, but try to imagine allocating lets say 100MB and not freeing it.

Also if you program for different devices than PC (lets say some microcontroller) with much less memory (maybe hundreds of KiB or MiB) it is much bigger issue.

To make it short - it might not hurt you in short term, but in long term, it could be big issue. It is very good practice to free allocated memory. If you don't want to do it manually, then you could look for some smart pointers and similar solutions (if you could use C++).

Comment: I just want to know what would it be like when it cause problem, does it make other program crash or make itself crash or make system to crash?

Comment: Imagine all applications allocate memory and don't free it. After some time system would run out of memory and start swapping (or even crash). So yes, it could make other applications or system crash, because they could not allocate memory.

Comment: thank you, I give you a "up"

Answer (score -1):

Try the following change to make it have enough allocated memory to cause problems if you don't free the allocated memory:

```
...
int i;
char *buff[30000];
for( i = 0; i < 30000; i++ ) {
    buff[i] = malloc(10000000);
    strcpy( buff[i], "Some String");
    puts(buff[i]);
}
...
```

That's nearly 300 gigabytes.

Comment: You might want to learn about deferred allocation and compiler optimisation. Then wonder why the code still works on a standard PC.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  Sorry.